# How to correctly create EventSource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want create EventSource for my Spring-Security application, but doing something wrong... Please, help me solve the problem.
On the server side, I created a controller:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap <Long, Integer> flagNotifications;

@GetMapping("/notifications")
    public @ResponseBody void streamSseNotifications(Principal principal) {
    if (principal!=null) {
        String email = principal.getName();
        Person pers = service.getUserByLogin(email);
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        sseExecutor.execute(() -> {
            long id = pers.getId();
            int countNotice = service.getCountNotice(id);
            try {
                while(true) {
                    if (countNotice==0 || flagNotifications.get(id)==countNotice) {
                         SseEventBuilder event = SseEmitter.event().name("ping");
                         emitter.send(event);
                    }
                    else {
                    countNotice = flagNotifications.get(id);
                    SseEventBuilder event = SseEmitter.event()
                      .name("notice")
                      .data(countNotice);
                    emitter.send(event);
                    }
                Thread.sleep(30000);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                emitter.completeWithError(ex);
                flagNotifications.remove(id);
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

On the client side "ready function":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (!window.EventSource) {
    // IE or an old browser
    alert("Your browser doesn't support push notifications.");
    return;
}else{
    const div = $('#myAlerts .glyphicon glyphicon-bell');  
    const source = new EventSource('/notifications');
    source.onopen = function() { alert("push");};
//  source.onerror = function(){ alert("error");
//      setTimeout(function(){ setSubscribe(); },5000); return;}
    source.addEventListener("ping", () => {alert("Ping");});
    source.addEventListener("notice", (e) => {
        alert("DATA");
        $(div).text(e.data);
    });
    }
});
```

In the browser log, I'm getting error:

> EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/plain") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

Comment: you need to set the MIME type `.data(countNotice, MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM);` if i remember correctly, its something like this

Comment: @Toerktumlare I tried it, but it doesn't work... I wrote solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to solve with [Flux - reactive representation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events)

```
@GetMapping("/notifications")
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> streamSseNotifications(Principal principal){
    Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> sent = null;
    if (principal!=null) {
        String email = principal.getName();
        Person pers = service.getUserByLogin(email);
        long id = pers.getId();
        int countNotice = service.getCountNotice(id);
        flagNotifications.put(id, countNotice);
        sent = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
              .map(sequence -> ServerSentEvent.<String> builder()
                .id(String.valueOf(sequence))
                  .event("notice")
                  .data(flagNotifications.get(id).toString())
                  .build());
    }
    return sent;
}
```

But not exactly what is needed... I want to reduce number of calls to the database, and tried to do it in the one Thread. It looks something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/notifications")
public SseEmitter streamSseNotifications(Principal principal) {
SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
if (principal!=null) {
    String email = principal.getName();
    Person pers = service.getUserByLogin(email);
    sseExecutor.execute(() -> {
        final long id = pers.getId();
        int countNotice = service.getCountNotice(id);
        flagNotifications.put(id, countNotice);
         try {
            while(true) {
                countNotice = flagNotifications.get(id);
                SseEventBuilder event = SseEmitter.event()
                  .name("notice")
                  .data(countNotice);
                emitter.send(event);
            Thread.sleep(30000);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            emitter.completeWithError(ex);
        }
    });
  }
return emitter;
}
```

That's doesn't work like I wanted... I getting error:

> org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequest

Thread, of course die with Exception, and every time called new method *streamSseNotifications()*, repeating all cycles. So, my final solution, is add two maps and remove Thread (sseExecutor):

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap <Long, Integer> countNotifications;
private final ConcurrentHashMap <String, Long> sessionID;
@GetMapping("/notifications")
public SseEmitter streamSseNotifications(Principal principal, HttpServletRequest req) {
    long id; int countNotice=0;
    String thisSession = req.getRequestedSessionId();
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter((long)60000);
if (sessionID.contains(thisSession)) {
    id = sessionID.get(thisSession);
    countNotice = countNotifications.get(id);
}
else if (principal!=null) {
    String email = principal.getName();
    Person pers = service.getUserByLogin(email);
    id = pers.getId();
    countNotice = service.getCountNotice(id);
    countNotifications.put(id, countNotice);
    sessionID.put(thisSession, id);
}
try {
    SseEventBuilder event = SseEmitter.event()
         .name("notice")
         .data(countNotice)
         .reconnectTime(30000);
         emitter.send(event);
        } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        emitter.completeWithError(ex);
    }
return emitter;
}
```

Exception *"Async request timed out"* persists, but it's work. If anyone knows how to do it more correctly, let me know in comments or add answer please.